# Checking MySql table for an entry and either UPDATE or INSERT with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am pulling data from the Crunchbase API and adding into a database.

I am not sure what the best unique identifier is for both companies, people, or other, but I am thinking the permalink would work as an id.

My question is how do I check if an entry has been added, if it has, then update/replace the data, and if the permalink doesnt exist, add the next row into the table as a new entity.

My current code:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM companies");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$num = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($num) // if the record exist, update it
    {
        mysql_query("UPDATE companies SET
            permalink='".$array['permalink']."',
            WHERE `permalink` = '" . $result['permalink'] . "'",$con);
    } 
    else{  
        mysql_query("INSERT into companies SET 
            permalink='".$array['permalink']."'",$con);
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

NOTE: The table is named "companies"

Comment: Google `insert on duplicate`.

Comment: Hi Jean. Were the answers below useful to you? You do not appear to have responded to any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try on duplicate key...

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO companies SET permalink='".$array['permalink']."' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE permalink=permalink ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you find a unique id, you can check if the record exists using that:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM companies WHERE `permalink` = '" . $result['permalink'] . "'");
```

Note that I actually changed the `SELECT *` too, because it is pretty inefficient to select *all* the columns if you just want to know *if* a value exists.

In general, I would recommend that you use some automatically incremented numerical field as a unique id. This is common practice in database design, and for (several) good reason(s). If you add a `AUTO_INCREMENT` field called `id` to your table, you could do

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM companies WHERE `permalink` = '" . $result['permalink'] . "'");
```

then check if you get an empty result set. If not, do the `UPDATE` using that ID (`UPDATE ... WHERE id = $id`), otherwise, do the `INSERT`.

By the way, check the syntax for `INSERT`, it is not using `SET` the way `UPDATE` does.

Finally, I don't know how you are constructing `$result["permalink"]`, but please use [mysql_escape_string](http://en.php.net/mysql_escape_string) to prevent SQL injection, if you have not already done so.

Answer (score 0):

Try on duplicate key... From the manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html